# Find an element in a List by comparing with another list in scala

Tags: scala

I have two list.

`val lis1= List("pt1","pt2","")`

`val lis2= List("pt1","")`

I need to find the empty string in the lis1 so I am trying to do

`val find= lis1.find(lis=>lis2.contains(""))`

Here instead returning me "" , its returning me ("pt1"). Kindly help me how can I get empty string instead of "pt1"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the intersection of the two lists. You can use `filter` + `contains`, similar to your original approach. Alternative you can use the `intersect` method.

```
val lis1 = List("pt1", "pt2", "")
val lis2 = List("pt1", "")

lis1.filter(item => lis2.contains(item))
// > res0: List[String] = List(pt1, "")

lis1.intersect(lis2)
// > res1: List[String] = List(pt1, "")
```